# Kernel does not load after modifying parameters and kernel image with Syslinux

Tags: linux-kernel, syslinux

```
# Config file for Syslinux -
# /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg

LABEL arch
    MENU LABEL Arch Linux
    LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux
    APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
    INITRD ../initramfs-linux-ck.img

LABEL archfallback
    MENU LABEL Arch Linux Fallback
    LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux
    APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
    INITRD ../initramfs-linux-fallback.img
```

I have just changed my `arch` config to load the CK image. However, upon boot, `fsck` fails complaining that `/dev/sda3` cannot be found. This is weird, because `archfallback` loads correctly as usual.

Also, I should add the parameter `elevator=bfq`. Should I do that with a new APPEND line?

EDIT: I just saw that there is also a `vmlinuz-linux-ck`. I'll try and report back. The kernel parameter quesion remains.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters the same problem, this is the correct way to configure it:

```
LABEL arch
    MENU LABEL Arch Linux
    LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux-ck
    APPEND elevator=bfq
    APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
    INITRD ../initramfs-linux-ck.img
```

As noted in the ArchWiki, to check that the BFQ/BFS scheduler are loaded you have to check the output of `dmesg | grep scheduler`.